# How do I copy a border in word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007

[image: i want this border]

I am making a report, I want different border in different section. I want to copy a particular border. Please help, Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a picture of what you're working on and what is it that you want to copy? A border of page, of a table, of a paragraph? What is it?

Comment: I want to copy the page border, see the image I have uploaded.

Answer (score 2):

You can choose where to apply the specific border to within the page border options window.

In the pop up window when you add a page border, go to the bottom right hand corner and it should have "Apply to:" with a drop down.

You should then be able to select "This Section". It will then apply your desired border to the page. You may already have the border style saved and ready to select if you are using different borders for each page. However, if not you may need to recreate the border each time.